# Cats versus Dogs with Cucumbers

Tags: warfare, weapons

In my world, dogs and cats are at war over a disputed territory between their kingdoms but they are at an impasse and have been for many years.

Somehow the dogs find out that cats are terrified of cucumbers. https://tenor.com/view/cat-scared-cat-vs-cucumber-gif-13209546 
They want to use this fact to finally win the war by driving the cats out of the disputed lands.

There is no technology in this world apart from what can be achieved with mouths and paws, but cats and dogs are roughly as intelligent as terrestrial humans.

**Question**

Assuming that dogs have access to extensive fields of wild cucumbers, how best can they use them to win the war?

Comment: Information needed to avoid closure as too story-based: Size and location of cat encampments, patrols, disposition of forces, same for the dogs, map of contested region with complete geography, nature of cucumbers including time from vine before rotting, growth period, climate requirements, etc. etc. etc.  And why on earth would a cat with human-esque intelligence be afraid of a cucumber? (and I'm one to usually take the OP at his/her word... but this one's a tough nut to swallow.)

Comment: * Clarification. The cucumber is a gourd not a nut.

Comment: @JBH - A lot of humans have an irrational fear of spiders. Their intelligence plays no part.

Comment: I have an irrational fears of bees and heights - and my intellect allows me to stand among the bees unmoved and to scale great heights without error.  Intellect *always* plays a part.  Just because the fear is irrational does not mean someone will always react in an uncontrolled manner.  That someone reacts in an uncontrolled way to an irrational fear strongly suggests an untrained intellect.  It's one of the reasons human soldiers are trained the way they are - to overcome irrational fears (including that of death).  Cat soldiers untrained to deal with their irrational fear of cucumbers? Bah.

Comment: @JBH I don't think soldiers' fears are irrational. They may be killed or maimed at any moment when on active duty. A lot of very intelligent people are known to have phobias, here's a list of some of them https://listverse.com/2010/11/03/10-well-known-people-and-their-phobias/ - Interestingly many historical figures have feared cats! (see under Napoleon in the above list)

Comment: A list of ten that doesn't include [Thanatophobia](https://www.verywellmind.com/thanatophobia-2671879).  Curious, since the [fear of death is thought to be the root of most phobias](https://tonic.vice.com/en_us/article/a3aamk/most-of-our-phobias-are-driven-by-the-fear-of-death).  [This is a better list of phobias](https://www.fearof.net/).

Comment: @JBH - Mine was a list of people not a list of phobias. This was to counter your argument that, *"an irrational fear strongly suggests an untrained intellect"*.  Many intellectuals have had phobias and can be highly superstitious as well.  Howard Hughes for instance wasn't short of a brain cell and certainly not of money. He was terrified of germs and eventually shut himself away in a hotel until he died. https://listverse.com/2013/05/04/10-most-eccentric-millionaires-and-billionaires/

Comment: Your question isn't asking about the responses of an individual, but of an army.  I apologize, but I still find the premise of your question to be, itself, irrational.  What value a military that wouldn't strive to control and overcome an irrational fear that *each and every soldier has?*  That's a mighty big weakness.

Comment: @JBH - This is turning into a discussion so I'll stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since it's mouths and paws only, you should just give every dog you sent to war a cucumber. Any cat that tries to stop them flees.

Then to maintain the territory and keep yourself safe you plant cucumbers. If they have some form of bags or carts they can use to drag a lot of cucumbers around allowing a small group of dogs to secure a larger portion. Then grow cucumbers there. Repeat till you are satisfied with the territory you've gained or wiped out the cats.

Comment: I don't think dogs are capable of making bags or carts. Building a rough shelter out of sticks is about their limit.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK were they to kill something and not damage some of it's guts severely they could use that as a bag. or drop something on a fallen branch and use that like a sled.

Comment: @Demigan - Thanks for your answer. I missed a vital piece of information from my question:-( It's too late for me to change it now. The reason they are fighting is that there are lots of small prey animals in the disputed area. These prey are herbivores and would eat any cucumbers they found. As you have given a good answer to my current question I'll accept it if no one comes up with a better one.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK You can and you should change your answer. My answer would still remain the same: You scare away the cats with the cucumbers, then lure any critters towards you with the cucumbers and eat any that try to eat your cucumbers. You can't protect all your cucumbers, but it will reduce the amount of dogs you need for any single area and provides your dogs with food! Since the cucumberplant is alive and well it also means there's not enough critters to eat everything.

Comment: @Demigan - I've accepted your answer anyway. Thanks. I actually left out several crucial facts so I plan to submit another more detailed question later.